# grpc unary-stream with redis pubsub - degradation with too many clients

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, publish-subscribe, nginx-ingress, aioredis

We have a python grpc (grpcio with asyncio) server which performs server side streaming of data consumed from redis PUB/SUB (using aioredis 2.x) , combining up to 25 channels per stream. With low traffic everything works fine, as soon as we reach 2000+ concurrent streams , the delivery of messages start falling behind.

Some setup details and what we tried so far:

- The client connections to GRPC are loadbalanced over kubernetes cluster with Ingress-NGINX controller, and it seems scaling (we tried 9 pods with 10 process instances each) doesn't help at all (loadbalancing is distributed evenly).
- We are running a five node redis 7.x cluster with 96 threads per replica.
- Connecting to redis with CLI client while GRPC falls behind - individual channels are on time while GRPC streams are falling behind
- Messages are small in size (40B) with a variable rate anywhere between 20-200 per second on each stream.
- Aioredis seems to be opening a new connection for each pubsub subscriber even if we're using capped connection pool for each grpc instance.
- Memory/CPU utilisation is not dramatic as well as Network I/O, so we're not getting bottlenecked there
- Tried identical setup with a very similar grpc server written in Rust, with similar results

Comment: Hi @mike_t, Are you getting any error messages? Have you enabled autoscaling in Pub/Sub? Also can you try increasing the nodes and CPU’s?

Comment: Autoscaling was enabled, but it didn't seem to have any effect. Eventualy we switched to zmq and got rid of redis pubsub completely, which helped addressing the issue

Comment: Hi @mike_t, I have posted the answer as Community wiki. So If my answer addressed your question, please consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0):

@mike_t, As you have mentioned in the comment, switching from Redis Pub/Sub to zmq has helped in resolving the issue.

[ZeroMQ](https://zeromq.org/) (also known as ØMQ, 0MQ, or zmq) is an open-source universal messaging library, looks like an embeddable networking library but acts like a concurrency framework. It gives you sockets that carry atomic messages across various transports like in-process, inter-process, TCP, and multicast.

You can connect sockets N-to-N with patterns like fan-out, pub-sub, task distribution, and request-reply. It's fast enough to be the fabric for clustered products. Its asynchronous I/O model gives you scalable multicore applications, built as asynchronous message-processing tasks.

It has a score of language APIs and runs on most operating systems.